# Creating folders + hyperlinks based on dynamic cell value (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little dilemma, maybe someone can help. I have a masterfile with many project names in it. I want to create folders with names based on number (1,2,3,etc) in column "B" plus each project name (column "F"), starting from row 4. Additionally adding a hyperlink in corresponding cells in column 'B". 
Looks like:

```
Column B      Column F
1             Project 1
2             Project 2
3             Project 3
```

This is what I Have perfectly working so far:

```
Sub CreateFolders()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xDir As String, xNumber As String, xProjectName As String, xWholeName As String, xFullPath As String
    Dim lstrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim fso As Object

    lstrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For i = 4 To lstrow

        xNumber = Range("B" & i).Value & "."
        xProjectName = " " & CleanName(Range("F" & i).Value)
        xWholeName = xNumber & xProjectName
        xDir = "O:\certainpath\"
        xFullPath = xDir & xWholeName

        If Not fso.FolderExists(xFullPath) Then
            fso.CreateFolder (xFullPath)
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("B" & i), Address:=xFullPath

        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function CleanName(strName As String) As String 

    CleanName = Replace(strName, "/", "")
     CleanName = Replace(CleanName, """", "")
      CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "?", "")
       CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "*", "")
        CleanName = Replace(CleanName, ":", ";")
         CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "<", "")
          CleanName = Replace(CleanName, ">", "")

End Function
```

Now what I also need is to add conditions for the following situation:

1. If I am inserting a new row somewhere in my list (i.e. new project), so I will have different numbering for the old ones. I DON'T want the macro to create new folder for old projects, just because numbering is different.
2. Adjust names of previously created folders to match new numbering in cells of column "B".
3. Update hyperlinks to them.

Comment: Are the project name guaranteed to be unique? If yes, what is the purpose of the prepended number in the folder name?

Comment: Yes always unique. Purpose of numbering before project name is to have all created folders arranged in same way as names in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and seems OK:

```
Sub CreateFolders()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xDir As String, xNumber As String, xProjectName As String
    Dim exFolder As String
    Dim xWholeName As String, xFullPath As String
    Dim lstrow As Long, i As Long, rngHL As Range


    lstrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    xDir = "O:\certainpath\"

    For i = 4 To lstrow

        xNumber = Range("B" & i).Value
        xProjectName = ". " & CleanName(Range("F" & i).Value)

        xWholeName = xNumber & xProjectName
        xFullPath = xDir & xWholeName

        'folder with exact name doesn't already exist?
        If Len(Dir(xFullPath, vbDirectory + vbNormal)) = 0 Then

            'no match, but is there a folder with the same project name?
            exFolder = Dir(xDir & "*" & xProjectName, vbDirectory + vbNormal)
            If Len(exFolder) > 0 Then
                'rename folder to use the new number
                Name (xDir & exFolder) As xFullPath
            Else
                'no existing project folder, so create a brand-new folder
                MkDir xFullPath
            End If

            'made a change, so add/update hyperlink
            Set rngHL = Range("B" & i)
            If rngHL.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then rngHL.Hyperlinks.Delete
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngHL, Address:=xFullPath

        End If

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir! It indeed does what was needed.